# How would I group these items together by month only in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query that is pulling data from the database.  Its grouping the items by their CheckDate.  I need to turn the CheckDate which is a standard DateTime into just the month so that is grouped by month with no other dates.  I can't figure out how to do that.

```
var query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
                    where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                    ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
                    group ech by ech.CheckDate into echG
                    orderby echG.Key descending
                    select echG;
```

Comment: if `CheckDate` is a `datetime`, you do know you can use some intellisense and by entering a . after this field, you'll get month?

Comment: It doesn't show a month. I am confident the field is a datetime

Comment: Is it a `Nullable<DateTime>` or `datetime?`.  If so, you would need to use `CheckDate.Value.Month`.

Comment: That did it. Thanks @heavyd

Comment: @TheDizzle - `datetime != datetime?` that's why I asked and that's why you didn't see `Month`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to turn the CheckDate which is a standard DateTime into just the month

If it truly is a `DateTime`, then this should do the trick.  Just group by the Month property on `CheckDate`.

```
var query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
            where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                  ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
            group ech by ech.CheckDate.Month into echG
            orderby echG.Key descending
            select echG;
```

If it is actually a `Nullable<DateTime>`, then you will need to check that the value exists, then group by Month if it does.

```
var query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
            where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                  ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client &&
                  ech.CheckDate.HasValue
            group ech by ech.CheckDate.Value.Month into echG
            orderby echG.Key descending
            select echG;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query-

```
var query = from ech in this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories
                    where ech.CompanyID == GlobalVariables.CompanyID &&
                    ech.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.Client
                    group ech by ech.CheckDate into echG
                    orderby echG.Key descending
                    select echG;
```

Could be simplified as-

```
var query = this.dbContext.EmployeeCheckHistories.Where(c=> 
     c.CompanyID == GlobalVariable.CompanyID 
     && c.Employees.ClientID == GlobalVariables.ClientID).GroupBy(d=> d.CheckDate.Month);
```